# Doxygen not rendering MathJax formulas in markdown file

Tags: markdown, doxygen, mathjax

As I understood, I should be able to write formulas with MathJax in the README.md if I create the HTML output of doxygen.
I set the following options for MathJax:

```
USE_MATHJAX       = YES
MATHJAX_FORMAT    = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH   = https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2
```

I then tried the following in the markdown file for generating formulas:

```
\f(
    \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}
\f)


\f[
    \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}
\f]


\f{
    \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}
\f}


\f$ \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2} \f$
```

But I only get the following output:

[image]

Is there something obviously off? Are there other options I need to check in the Doxyfile?

Comment: Do you see the MathJax library being included in the generated HTML? Are you getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @Chris Thank you, the console showed the errors!

Answer (score 1):

The console showed that the CDN could not be reached due to the fact, that the internet connection in the virtual box suddenly stopped working.
It may be better to have a local copy of MathJax to not run into similar issues.